# why do we use weak reference in java?

Tags: java, jvm

```
B b = new B();
```

Here b is strong reference, then we set b as null.

```
b = null;
```

then GC will reclaim the object which referenced to b when GC happens.

My question is what is the point of using weak reference? as i understand it, the only reason to use weak reference, so we can still get the object even after we set reference as null before GC reclaims it. am i correct?

Comment: [The Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) describes some uses.

Comment: `so we can still get the object even after we set reference as null before GC` No, it's so the reference won't prevent the GC from collecting.  A regular reference (strong) hold the object no matter what.  A weak reference allows other code to finish with the reference and allows the object to be GC'ed when that other code releases the reference.

Comment: A WeakReference will keep a reference provided it is still being used somewhere else in the code. It is useful when you don't expect to be notified the reference is no longer needed.